# Get the file of same directory

Tags: cmd, directory, call

I want to ask a question.

I would like to "call" a file in directory-of-file\program.

> call *\program\test.bat

How can I do this?

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%~dp0` gives you the directory, where your running batchfile resides.

so this should do:

```
call %~dp0\subdir\test.bat
```

Comment: Thank you! That's **EXACTLY** what I want to do! Thanks ^.^

Comment: @user3186610 - Then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark neqr the upper left corner of the answer.

Comment: Sorry. Vote up require 15 reputation. I haven't got it.

Comment: voting up requires reputation - accept answer as correct doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This will call the `program\test.bat` file, when the `program` folder is located where the `current batch file` is.

```
call "program\test.bat"
```